# Collision Detection System

Tags: c#-4.0, xna

I am trying to make a simple platforming game. The player is a square and all of the platforms are squares. I am a beginner in XNA but I have modest C# 4.0 Experience.

The problem with my code is that when my character passes through the underside of a platform he continues to go through even though I set it up so that he shouldn't.

In Advance I would like to ask if anyone can help me because I cannot fix this.

Here is how the different pieces of code work together:

- In the platform struct the image is loaded and an enum is stored which can hold one of three values: passable(can go through), impassible (completely solid), and platform (can go through bottom and stop on top)
- A collision detection method which needs to be fixed (it checks for intersections, checks the enum of that particular platform, then determines if it can be passed through or not and returns an array which contains: {isabove, isbelow, isleft, isright} of the platform)

  - It does return true if the player is on top of the platform but nothing happens when they hit the bottom
- My player's vertical motion which deals with gravity and vertical motion, it may be the culprit but I cannot tell. The collision check is run in the update loop at the beginning and then the vertical motion method is run afterwards

Here is the code for the collision:

```
    public bool[] environmentCollisionDetect(Charachter thing, ScreenObjects sreenobjectlist, bool[] platformstatus)
    {
        //Defaults the collision to false
        platformstatus[0] = false;  //Above platform
        platformstatus[1] = false;  //Below Platform
        platformstatus[2] = false;  //Left
        platformstatus[3] = false;  //Right

        //Store the player in boxA
        boxA.Height = thing.image.Height;
        boxA.Width = thing.image.Width;
        boxA.X = (int)thing.position.X;
        boxA.Y = (int)thing.position.Y;

        //Find a collision
        foreach (Platform platform in screenobjectlist)
        {
            //Makes sure the platform cannot be passed through
            if (platform.platformCollisionProperty != platformCollision.passable)
            {
                //Store the platform's rectangle
                boxB = platform.destinationrectangle;
                boxB.Height = platform.image.Height;
                boxB.Width = platform.image.Width;
                boxB.X = (int)platform.destinationrectangle.X;
                boxB.Y = (int)platform.destinationrectangle.Y;

                //Collision Check
                if (boxA.Intersects(boxB))
                {
                    switch (platform.platformCollisionProperty)
                    {
                        //Platform is Solid
                        case platformCollision.impassible:

                            //Player is below it
                            if (boxA.Top > boxB.Bottom)
                            {
                                platformstatus[1] = true;
                            }

                            //Player is above it
                            if (boxA.Bottom > boxB.Top)
                            {
                                platformstatus[0] = true;
                            }
                            break;

                        //Platform can be passed through bottom
                        case platformCollision.platform:
                            if (boxA.Bottom > boxB.Top)
                            {
                                platformstatus[0] = true;
                            }
                            break;
                    }

                    break;
                }
            }
        }
      return platformstatus;
    }
```

Here is the Vertical Motion Code:

- the isJumping bool is set to true when the jump button is activated
- the isinair bool is used only within this loop to determine if the player is still gliding through the air
- Finally i is used as a counter because I couldn't get a timer to work

  ```
  public void verticalMotionI(GameTime gametime)
  {
      //Resets the bools if not standing on platform
      if ((this.isJumping == true) && (this.platformstatus[0] == false))
      {
          this.i = 0;
          this.isJumping = false;
          this.isinair = false;
      }

      //Jumps if A button is activated and standing on a platform
      else if ((this.isJumping == true) && (this.platformstatus[0] == true))
      {
          //Set up bools to jump
          this.isJumping = false;
          this.isinair = true;

          //Overwrites the start time
          this.starttime = currentime;

          //Move up
          this.position.Y -= this.playermovementspeed * 1.5f;

          //Increase counter
          this.i++;
      }

      //Pulls stops moving player if jumptimer had elapsed
      else if ((this.isinair == true) && (i == this.jumptime))
      {
          this.isinair = false;

          //Apply gravity
          Gravity.forceofGravity(this);
      }

      //Stops the jump if bottom of a platform is hit
      else if ((this.isinair == true) && (this.platformstatus[1] == true))
      {
          //Reset bools
          this.isinair = false;

          //reset I
          this.i = 0;

          //Apply gravity
          Gravity.forceofGravity(this);
      }

      //Continues the jump if in air
      else if ((this.isinair == true) && (this.platformstatus[1] == false))
      {
          //Move up
          this.position.Y -= this.playermovementspeed * 1.5f;

          //Increase counter
          this.i++;
      }

      //Apply Gravity
      else if ((this.isinair == false) && (this.platformstatus[0] == false))
      {
          //reset I
          this.i = 0;

          Gravity.forceofGravity(this);
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: Just looking through the code, curious as to why you did this: `boxB = platform.destinationrectangle;
                boxB.Height = platform.image.Height;
                boxB.Width = platform.image.Width;
                boxB.X = (int)platform.destinationrectangle.X;
                boxB.Y = (int)platform.destinationrectangle.Y;`  I doubt it's related to the problem but destinationRectangle should already have all those values. You are setting our Rectangle to the destination rectangle then manually setting each of its values again! I'll continue looking through the code...

Comment: `if (boxA.Top > boxB.Bottom)` - this condition should never be true if `boxA.Intersects(boxB)`. Did you mean `if (boxA.Top < boxB.Bottom && boxA.Top > boxB.Center)`, perhaps? That would mean the top of boxA is colliding with the lower half of boxB. Also, could you clarify the problem you are having-- is your character falling through solid/'platform' platforms or jumping up through solid platforms? Also consider an enum for platformStatus, as I can't really tell what it means right now.

Comment: Sorry, can't edit the previous comment but I meant `if (boxA.Top < boxB.Bottom && boxA.Top > boxB.Center.Y)`, as Center is a Point.

Comment: Thanks alot, switching the > for  the < fixes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If Gravity does what I assume, It doesn't look like you explicitly set the player position when it hits the platform, what I am seeing is your switch your isInAir flag, and apply gravity...  For testing purposes and to solve your problem, try something like this pseudocode:

```
if(dude is jumping & dude collides with platform){
   set the top of dudes head to be at position under the platform;
}
```

hope this can help. :)

Not to beat a dead horse or be an ass, but you are reinventing the wheel.  Check out some of the physics engines out there.  I have been toying around with Farseer 3+, and it is wonderful.  There is a slight learning curve when first figuring out the World Body Fixture pattern, but once you have your epiphany it will be cake to set some properties on your body/fixtures and fire off OnCollision methods.

Farseer is a Box2D Physics Engine Port to .NET, it's open source, and it's amazing once you bang through the learning curve.

Take a quick look at [this farseer doc](http://farseerphysics.codeplex.com/documentation) and you'll probably like what you see. :)
Even if you don't fall in love with it, it is open source and could give you some ideas on how to *cough*copy* implement some of the functionality with your own twist.

You don't need to implement all the fun intricacies of the engine if all you want is a simple jumping, object state, and interaction functionality, which is all nicely wrapped into Farseer.

Comment: also here is a nice walkthrough on youtube that helped me mindlessly lay some code down. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ejJA9MWXwJ0  additionally, if you decide to try it, download the engine off http://farseerphysics.codeplex.com/ , build the project, reference the dll that pops into the bin directory and happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

`if (boxA.Top > boxB.Bottom)` - this condition should never be true if `boxA.Intersects(boxB)`. Did you mean `if (boxA.Top < boxB.Bottom && boxA.Top > boxB.Center.Y)`?

Just reposting my comment explorations as an answer for future reference. Since I have room in an answer and not a comment, I can also explain a few things.

Obviously, `Rectangle.Intersects(Rectangle)` is only going to be true if they overlap in some way. The trick is, in interpreting that, we need to remember that Y coordinates on the screen actually move from top to bottom. Y = 0 is at the top of the screen, and Y =  is at the bottom. This may seem backwards if you're new to 2D game programming, but that's just the way graphics adapters work.

So, by saying that the top of boxA is > the bottom of boxB, what you are really saying is the top of boxA is below the bottom of boxB on the screen, which will never be true as we already know they overlap. I turned around the conditional and added an additional point of logic in order to provide the needed functionality. `boxA.Top > boxB.Center.Y` means that your boxA is specifically intersecting *below* boxB. If I had left it as just `boxA.Top < boxB.Bottom`, the conditional would also be true if boxA was falling from *above* boxB, which I don't think you wanted considering we must discriminate between platforms and solid blocks for logic involving the player below the tile, so we must make this distinction in the code. Also, of course, your comment said `//player is below it`.

Finally, a word of debugging advice: if you notice certain behavior is not occuring, place a breakpoint on the line(s) which dictate(s) that behavior (in this case, `platformstatus[1] = true`). If you never hit that breakpoint, you know now why it isn't happening. Now simply place a breakpoint on the enclosing conditional. When it hits that breakpoint, manually look at the values, compare them to what is expected, and see if you used the appropriate logic. Everyone makes mistakes in conditionals sometimes, it's one of my first points of weakness, personally.